# WPF MenuItem input gesture text in different locales

Tags: wpf, locale, menuitem

I have a WPF program with a menu. I set the menu like the following

```
<Menu Height="23" Name="menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="fileMenuItem">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.SaveAs"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save All" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Name="editMenuItem">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

When the program runs, I have different locales of the input gesture texts of the menu items under the menu "File" and "Edit". The items under "File" are in German (e.g. Strg+N) but those under "Edit" are in English (e.g. Ctrl+C). Plus the all the headers are in German (e.g. Öffnen). I did not set anything that has something to do with the locale anywhere in my code.

And my system is Windows 7 in German, Visual Studio 2012 in English. Not sure if this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

To set the system default language for the program need to add handler in App.xaml.cs:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
     FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
}
```

In App.xaml:

```
<Application ... Startup="Application_Startup">
```

Set a specific language system can set the parameters for the thread:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

But in your situation, most likely **not installed** satellite assembly with *German* language.

See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9d3f9534-4a10-4860-90b5-d2ea5c967fca

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but sorry, none of your suggestions work for me, except the satellite assembly with German language, which I did not figure out how it works yet, but it could be tip for the next step! Btw, when I set the culture info in the constructor of the MainWindow, I got a very strange XML parser exception.